# xpath-locator plugin in firefox

Tags: xpath, selenium, selenium-rc

Is xpath-locator plug-in for Firefox can help in locating the elements in selenium script.

Any limitation using this plug-in in script?

Comment: What do you mean by limitation? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Alp for example as Xpath locator plug-in gives absolute path of the element not relative path & If element is appears dynamically on the webpage will it helpful.

Comment: You already answered your own question.

Comment: Thanks @Alp So this means it will get fail on locating the dynamic elements and it is not useful at all in selenium script : any comments please..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always better to create your own xpath using firebug, firepath (a firebug extension) , webdeveloper or any other tool. You will learn to create xpaths which are not brittle. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot A.J,Please provide if you know any good link to learn the xpath creation.

Comment: with FF56+ there is no firebug support :( .. waiting for good extentions on firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very generic. It is not possible to cover all or at least the most variants of dynamically generated HTML source code to find elements by just using Xpath or CSS selectors. You will need a more "intelligent" logic.

If you tell us what your exact task is, we may help you with a solution for your problem.